# Fixing corrupted unicode text file after system crash

Tags: unicode

I have a text file which contains unicode persian text (Arabic units).
My system crashed and after reboot I found my file corrupted.
the file currently displays text like this:

```
гУКдП ПСИЗСе Мдђ жнКдЗг ж ВгСнЗУК
гХЗНИе еЗн ВСФнжн КжФ геге
ПЮнЮе 3:27 Ун е ПЗСе дФжд гнПе ЗУгФ едСн УндМС ЗПг Онбн гегн е Кжн ВСФнж ЭжбПС Ие ЗУгФ ПЗСнг ИЪП ЗТ Знд ЛЗдне гнТде КХЗнС МПнП УндМС е ПЗСе ХНИК гнде ЗждЗ Сж ег ИђнС
ЗПгн е ЗТ 5:28 дФжд гнПе ЗУгФ ђСЗеЗг гЗСКнд УЭнС ВгСнЗ ПС жнКдЗг МджИн КХЗжнСФ Сж ИђнС
Ун е ПЮнЮе 16:48 ПЗСе ХНИК гнде МСЗбП ЭжСП СЖнУ МгежС ВгСнЗУК НжЗУК Ие КХЗжнСФ ИЗФе еге Сж ИђнС
ЪУ еЗн КжФ геге
гХЗНИе еЗн МПнП Сж дгнОжЗнг
```

the clocks are correct ! so `3:27` and `5:28` and `16:48` and space characters are displayed correctly but the rest of text is corrupted.
I used a hex editor and checked unicode units:

```
EF BB BF D0 B3 D0 A3 D0 9A D0 B4 D0 9F 20 D0 9F D0 A1 D0 98 D0 97 D0 A1 D0 B5 20 D0 9C D0 B4 D1 92 20 D0 B6 D0 BD D0 9A D0 B4 D0 97 D0 B3 20 D0 B6 20 D0 92 D0 B3 D0 A1 D0 BD C2 98 D0 97 D0 A3 D0 9A 0D 0A D0 B3 D0 A5 D0 97 D0 9D D0 98 D0 B5 20 D0 B5 D0 97 D0 BD 20 D0 92 D0 A1 D0 A4 D0 BD D0 B6 D0 BD 20 D0 9A D0 B6 D0 A4 20 D0 B3 D0 B5 D0 B3 D0 B5 0D 0A D0 9F D0 AE D0 BD D0 AE D0 B5 20 33 3A 32 37 20 C2 98 D0 A3 D0 BD 20 C2 98 D0 B5 20 D0 9F D0 97 D0 A1 D0 B5 20 D0 B4 D0 A4 D0 B6 D0 B4 20 D0 B3 D0 BD D0 9F D0 B5 20 D0 97 D0 A3 D0 B3 D0 A4 20 D0 B5 D0 B4 D0 A1 D0 BD 20 C2 98 D0 A3 D0 BD D0 B4 D0 9C D0 A1 20 D0 97 D0 9F D0 B3 20 D0 9E D0 BD D0 B1 D0 BD 20 D0 B3 D0 B5 D0 B3 D0 BD 20 C2 98 D0 B5 20 D0 9A D0 B6 D0 BD 20 D0 92 D0 A1 D0 A4 D0 BD D0 B6 20 D0 AD D0 B6 D0 B1 D0 9F D0 A1 20 D0 98 D0 B5 20 D0 97 D0 A3 D0 B3 D0 A4 20 D0 9F D0 97 D0 A1 D0 BD D0 B3 20 D0 98 D0 AA D0 9F 20 D0 97 D0 A2 20 D0 97 D0 BD D0 B4 20 D0 9B D0 97 D0 B4 D0 BD D0 B5 20 D0 B3 D0 BD D0 A2 D0 B4 D0 B5 20 D0 9A D0 A5 D0 97 D0 BD D0 A1 20 D0 9C D0 9F D0 BD D0 9F 20 C2 98 D0 A3 D0 BD D0 B4 D0 9C D0 A1 20 C2 98 D0 B5 20 D0 9F D0 97 D0 A1 D0 B5 20 D0 A5 D0 9D D0 98 D0 9A 20 D0 B3 D0 BD C2 98 D0 B4 D0 B5 20 D0 97 D0 B6 D0 B4 D0 97 20 D0 A1 D0 B6 20 D0 B5 D0 B3 20 D0 98 D1 92 D0 BD D0 A1 0D 0A D0 97 D0 9F D0 B3 D0 BD 20 C2 98 D0 B5 20 D0 97 D0 A2 20 35 3A 32 38 20 D0 B4 D0 A4 D0 B6 D0 B4 20 D0 B3 D0 BD D0 9F D0 B5 20 D0 97 D0 A3 D0 B3 D0 A4 20 D1 92 D0 A1 D0 97 D0 B5 D0 97 D0 B3 20 D0 B3 D0 97 D0 A1 D0 9A D0 BD D0 B4 20 D0 A3 D0 AD D0 BD D0 A1 20 D0 92 D0 B3 D0 A1 D0 BD C2 98 D0 97 20 D0 9F D0 A1 20 D0 B6 D0 BD D0 9A D0 B4 D0 97 D0 B3 20 D0 9C D0 B4 D0 B6 D0 98 D0 BD 20 D0 9A D0 A5 D0 97 D0 B6 D0 BD D0 A1 D0 A4 20 D0 A1 D0 B6 20 D0 98 D1 92 D0 BD D0 A1 0D 0A C2 98 D0 A3 D0 BD 20 C2 98 D0 B5 20 D0 9F D0 AE D0 BD D0 AE D0 B5 20 31 36 3A 34 38 20 D0 9F D0 97 D0 A1 D0 B5 20 D0 A5 D0 9D D0 98 D0 9A 20 D0 B3 D0 BD C2 98 D0 B4 D0 B5 20 D0 9C D0 A1 D0 97 D0 B1 D0 9F 20 D0 AD D0 B6 D0 A1 D0 9F 20 D0 A1 D0 96 D0 BD D0 A3 20 D0 9C D0 B3 D0 B5 D0 B6 D0 A1 20 D0 92 D0 B3 D0 A1 D0 BD C2 98 D0 97 D0 A3 D0 9A 20 D0 9D D0 B6 D0 97 D0 A3 D0 9A 20 D0 98 D0 B5 20 D0 9A D0 A5 D0 97 D0 B6 D0 BD D0 A1 D0 A4 20 D0 98 D0 97 D0 A4 D0 B5 20 D0 B5 D0 B3 D0 B5 20 D0 A1 D0 B6 20 D0 98 D1 92 D0 BD D0 A1 0D 0A D0 AA C2 98 D0 A3 20 D0 B5 D0 97 D0 BD 20 D0 9A D0 B6 D0 A4 20 D0 B3 D0 B5 D0 B3 D0 B5 0D 0A D0 B3 D0 A5 D0 97 D0 9D D0 98 D0 B5 20 D0 B5 D0 97 D0 BD 20 D0 9C D0 9F D0 BD D0 9F 20 D0 A1 D0 B6 20 D0 B4 D0 B3 D0 BD D0 9E D0 B6 D0 97 D0 BD D0 B3
```

but it doesnt seem match any unicode char in persian (which start from `d880` to `dbbf` or code points from `0600` to `06ff`) while space (unit `20`) and latin numbers are correct!

is there any way to fix this text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it has perhaps been read using the wrong encoding (KO18?) causing the Persian code-point values to be read as Cyrillic and then saved using the UTF8 encoding for Cyrillic,

```
EF BB BF   - Byte Order Mark 0xFEFF in UTF-8 encoding


D0 B3   - Common Cyrillic characters in UTF8 start with D0, D1 or D2
D0 A3 
D0 9A 
D0 B4 
D0 9F 
20      - Space character
D0 9F 
D0 A1 
D0 98 
D0 97
```

If you know what the Arabic characters were for the first few words, you may be able to deduce a numeric transformation needed to reverse the incorrect re-encoding. Not all transformations are reversible of course.

I don't read Arabic/Persian so I've no idea what transformations result in sensible text.

For example changing the D0s to D8 changes

> гУКдП ПСИЗСе

to

> سأؚش؟ ؟ءؘؗءص

Which Google translates to

> I'll be back? What?

But I've no idea whether that is nonsense. It certainly looks like nonsense.

Some time spent playing about in a similar fashion may lead to a solution.